# JS FileSaver non interactive

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesaver.js

I have an array of file to save by using a loop and i generate the name of each file. I want to save file directly (in non interactive way) without asking me to confirm. How can i do ?
Here is my code for saving file

```
var url = img.src.replace(/^data:image\/[^;]/, 'data:application/octet-stream');

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.responseType = 'blob'; //Set the response type to blob so xhr.response returns a blob
xhr.open('GET', url , true);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == xhr.DONE) {
        var filesaver = require('file-saver');
        filesaver.saveAs(xhr.response, nameFile); // nameFile the name of file to be saved
    }
};
xhr.send(); //Request is sent
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, the file-saver package cannot save files in a non-interactive way.

Comment: do you have a suggestion for saving file in js

Comment: the best i could imagine is creating a zip file, pack all files, give that to the user with one save popup. there is no automatic file saving function in browsers. that would be a serious security risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i find a solution, instead of saving file, i write it by creating a new one.

```
for (var i = 0; i < tabForm.length; i++) {

    var imgData = $('#affichageqr')[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].src;

    var data = imgData.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, '');

    fs.writeFile(qrcode.getNomQRCode()+'.jpeg', data, {encoding: 'base64'}, function(err){
      if (err) {
        console.log('err', err);
      }
     console.log('success');
    });
  }
```